# Webforms Ajax practices and fallback for IE

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, user-controls, webforms

Looking at next.co.uk as an example, I am looking to create a new swish site that slides panels in using webforms and updatepanels and/or jquery ajax.

However if you notice on next.co.uk, when you click a item in department navigation at the top, in Chrome and FF it slides everything in, however in IE7, 8 and 9 it does a normal postback.

What is the recommended way of doing this? i.e the would it be wise to use ascx user controls for everything and wrap the site master in an update panel to slide them in dynamically? Also how would one go about creating a fallback for IE or older browsers which can't support the fast sliding ajax panels? - as they would need to do a full postback as normal.

I can understand using MVC would be easier  to do this but my limitations are that I am using VS2008 Webforms.

Comment: This site as I see it is very advanced, very difficult one. There is not recommended way, only the imagination and the good code of this developer. If you won to start, start from the full post back, then after some months you can move it to ajax.

Comment: @Aristos thanks for your reply, the thing is a site with basic postback is quick and easy to implement, I'm looking for the best practices really how to implement this using webforms and ajax. Sliding panels for every page..

Comment: quick and easy... :) ... its just made the page on background and send it with ajax.

Comment: @Aristos I understand that bit, but what is the recommended way using webforms? I can make the page in a control and slide that control in but that control is dead code without the html/form tags, however I cant slide a whole aspx page in with html form tags because asp.net webforms only allows one form, so the postback stops working when sliding in items from pages. Does that make sense?